# What is the issue with this Python code?

Tags: python

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.name=x
        self.family=y
    def enter(self):
        self.name=input("enter name=")
        self.family=input("enter family=")
    def show(self):
        print("self.name",self.name,"enter family=",self.family)

object=a('sam','salam')
object.show()


object1=a()
object1.enter()
object1.show()
```

I want to call and enter name and family name in this code. When I use o=a('sam','salam') as the first object, there is no problem. although there is a problem with object1=a() as the second object. When I run, I receive:

> object1=a() TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments:
>   'x' and 'y'

What is the problem with and how can I eliminate that?
Thanks,

Comment: You can't just take away `a`'s name and family. That's too cruel.

Comment: I guess you have to set default values for x and y

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles for your questions. "Why is my code not working" is not a good title.

Comment: Do not use `object` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `object` type. Also, the convention in Python is for class names to begin with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code I get the following exception:

> TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

You have to pass `x` and `y` arguments to the constructor or define default values:

Arguments to the constructor:

```
object1 = a("name", "family")
```

Default values:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x="", y=""):
    ...
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more via example. I did not understand.

Comment: You have to pass arguments through the contructor, as you did: object=a('sam','salam'). If there isn't args, the contructor cannot know what is 'x' or 'y'

Comment: But I want to use object1.enter() without defining any name through constructor.

Comment: Then define default values for your X and Y attributes: def __init__(self,x="",y=""):

Comment: you mean I should use o1=a('x','y'). Am I write?

Comment: Yes you can. But if I understood your problem, you should modify the definition of your __init__ method from def __init__(self,x,y): to def __init__(self,x="",y=""):

Comment: OK. If I use def __init__(self,x="",y=""), for the second object, it will return null to constructor and I can enter name and family. But how about the first? When "sam" and "salam" return to constructor, what will happen for null or x=" " and y=" "?

Comment: It won't return null to contructor, It initalize name and family to empties strings that's all. For the first object, nothing will change

Comment: So, When I use the first object, names will replace with empties strings. and for second one it will not change till the time that I enter names. Is that right?

Comment: Nope. When you use the first object, names will be replaced by 'sam' & 'salam' but for second one names will be replaced by empties strings

Comment: How does def__init__(self,x="",y="") act when we use o=a('sam','salam'). what will happen for empties strings?

Comment: x="" and y="" are default values. If you pass other values, those will be used instead of default ones